# Есть ли библиотека для распаковки архива с паролем?

Tags: c++

мне нужно с помощью c++ распаковать архив который должен быть под паролем, какой это будте архив (7z, zip, т.д.) не имеет значения мне подойдёт любой, ну или почти любой. Посоветуйте пожалуйста библиотеки и желательно что-бы они были не очень большими по размеру т.е. в идеале что-бы там были только функции создания и распаковки архива, но буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Это можно сделать с помощью того же WinRAR (cli)

Comment: Есть же дока - https://libzip.org/documentation/zip_fopen_encrypted.html